# Android RecyclerView database remove item

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to remove item from RecyclerView list that is populated from SQLite DB and getting this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
```

The code I'm trying with is working with data that's not populated from SQLite database, but in this case it crashes on long click. Here's my code:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Todo item = listData.get(position);

        final int currentPosition = position;
        final Todo infoData = listData.get(position);

        holder.container.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                removeData(infoData);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private void removeData(Todo infoData) {
        int position = dbTodo.indexOf(infoData);
        dbTodo.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**SOLUTION**

I've messed up with this `db.Todo` in `removeData()`, it should be `listData` like in inicialisation.

Answer (score 0):

The error signifies that `infoData` is not found in the `dbTodo` - hence `indexOf` returns `-1`, and so in your subsequent line, you remove something at index `-1` (which is obvisouly out of bounds). To get rid of this error, you must just check that `infoData` does exist before trying to remove it.

```
 private void removeData(Todo infoData) {
        int position = dbTodo.indexOf(infoData);
       //here you check that it exists before you try to remove it
        if(position >= -1){
         dbTodo.remove(position);
         notifyItemRemoved(position);
       }
      else{
          //do something else here?
       }
    }
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that position you tried to use to get item from is incorrect.

```
dbTodo.indexOf(infoData)
```

return you -1 if it didn't find infoData object, so you have to choices:
1) Check position before trying to remove object from database

```
if(position >= -1){
     dbTodo.remove(position);
     ......
```

2) Check infoData is really in database before trying to remove it.